# Does the boost.signals2 library need to be built?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-signals, boost-signals2

My system is having trouble building the boost libraries. I understand that most boost libraries are (fortunately) just headers that do not need to be build (with some exceptions). Does the boost :: signals2 library need to be built? Also is the boost.signals2 library dependant on the boost.signals library?

Comment: Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98590/attention-grabbing-questioners

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Signals is not header-only, signals2 is. But however, signals2 is explicitly developed for thread-safety and if you use boost.thread, this has to be compiled. As far as I know signals2 is not dependent on signals headers.

Comment: +1: Beat me to it! BTW. Only some parts of boost threads need to be compiled and linked and IIRC the mutexs signals2 uses do not.

Comment: Yay! Frankly I hate building libraries, why can't people provide binaries themselves? (+1 and accept)

Comment: @burningprodigy: what? because it's a free world. In fact, so free that you can simply `apt-get install libboost-dev' on the [majority](http://distrowatch.com/stats.php?section=popularity) of linux boxes.

Comment: @ApprenticeHacker: did you ever take a look at the number of supported compilers and Operating Systems? If you can't figure out how to compile a Boost library then C++ is probably not for you anyway..

Answer (score 1):

No, signals2 is header only. See [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/signals2/tutorial.html#id2697983).