# Boost linker errors when using header-only libraries

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, header, linker-errors

I am using the following components of Boost 1.53.0 in conjunction with C++11 libraries...

- boost::signals2::scoped_connection
- boost::signals2::signal
- boost::signals2::connection
- boost::math::constants
- boost::circular_buffer
- boost::lexical_cast

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13604090/list-of-header-only-boost-libraries), I do not need to link against libraries to use these parts of Boost. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690721/does-the-boost-signals2-library-need-to-be-built), signals2 should be header-only also. However, I still receive linker errors...

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "boost::system::system_category()", referenced from:
  ___cxx_global_var_init2 in Main.o
  ...
  "boost::system::generic_category()", referenced from:
  ___cxx_global_var_init in Main.o
  ___cxx_global_var_init1 in Main.o
  ...
```

Why?

Comment: A quick browse of the documentation for Signals2 in Boost 1.53.0 also says that it's header only.  I'm reasonably sure the others are too.  However... are you sure you don't have, say, Boost.Asio in that list too?  That requires linking with Boost.System for its error codes.

Comment: You just excluded the interesting part: `referenced from: ...` from where? That part will give you the info wich lib/function calls Boost.System

Comment: @ArneMertz added some detail . . the rest is a list of other files giving the same `___cxx_global_var_init` type messages

Comment: please give us the full compiler error, and also your full list of Boost packages. E.g. Boost.Asio also uses Boost.system if I am not mistaken

Comment: Problem solved . . see Answer. Darn I feel stupid :S Thanks all

Answer (score 2):

Boost.Signals2 is indeed header-only, but [Boost.System is not](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#header-only-libraries). You have to make sure that you don't have any dependency on that library. If it's in your own code, you have to build Boost.System and link against it. If it's called from any header-only Boost library, [file a bug report](http://www.boost.org/development/bugs.html).

Answer (score 2):

The problem was a spurious

```
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
```

accidentally left in the middle of a file.